# How to I access the <div id="example"> of another html page?

Tags: javascript, html

The URL is the same, but the path is different and I want to see how I can access the example id contents of a previous html page. Thoughts?

Comment: You can use `localStorage`

Comment: You need to read SO's FAQ about how to post a question.

Comment: iFrame or storage would help ?

Comment: URL is the same, but the path is different? It's not possible, since path is the part of the URL.

Comment: In jQuery, do Ajax call to this page with the div. Assuming that you have its contents in `html` variable, you can do `$('#example', html).html()` or `$('#example', html).text()`.

Comment: the url is the same like www.example.com, but after the / is different. www.example.com/different/path/here

Answer (score 0):

In JS you could use local storage.

HTML:

```
<div id="example> </div>
```

JS:

```
//assign the value of the id
localStorage.setItem('value', example);

//get and assign the value 
var value= localStorage.getItem("value");
```